# SwiftUI Keyboard Word Suggestion Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, keyboard

How do I remove the word suggestion bar on the keyboard? I tried .disableAutocorrection(true) but it doesn't seem to actually hide it as shown in the image. If I use a secureField, then obviously, it will hide it, but how can I do that with a regular textfield?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set your `TextField` up this way:

```
        TextField("Enter some text...", text: $someText)
            .keyboardType(.alphabet)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
```

Just `.disableAutocorrection(true)` leaves the remnants of the suggestion bar, but adding the `.keyboardType(.alphabet)` makes it all go away.

Comment: Thank you very much! Test on IOS15 and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately on iOS 15, this forces the keyboard to only allow ASCII-compatible characters, so it will hide Emoji and UTF-8 keyboards (like Russian), so it's a fix with compromises.

Comment: In Xcode 14.1 .alphabet has the comment "// deprecated" after it. So hopefully Apple will make just .disableAutocorrection(true) work soon

Comment: `.disableAutocorrection(true)` has been deprecated and is now `.autocorrectionDisabled()`

Comment: It works only by using two methods: 

`.keyboardType(.alphabet).disableAutocorrection(true)`

...in the old version of Xcode, of course

Comment: `.alphabet` is now deprecated.  But using `.keyboardType(.asciiCapable).autocorrectionDisabled(true)` worked for me (using Xcode 15.2).

Answer (score 2):

for that what I would do is to change the type of keyboard that you are using, pretty much any other keyboard type in combination with `.disableAutocorrection(true)` will do the trick, it really depends on what you need the user to input inside your TextField.

so for example you can do something like this...

```
TextField("test",text: $string)
            .font((Font.system(size: 17, design: .default)))
            .lineLimit(1)
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)/// Disable autocorrection 
            .frame(width: screenSize.size.width*(0.5), height: 30,alignment: .center)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.7))
            .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)/// KEYBOARD TYPE
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
```

It is worth mentioning that some keyboards in languages such as Chinese or Japanese won't hide the Keyboard (only using a SecureField they will be hidden)

Comment: Thank you. I think this solution is more or less the same as @Yrb's, so it also worked.

Answer (score 1):

I want to write this as an answer to get the syntax highlighting. It is based on Yrb's answer. It is modifier that allows you to have a function where the keyboard type is flexible. It just changes .default to .alphabet to make it work.

```
extension View {

  func noAutoSuggestions(_ keyBd: UIKeyboardType) -> some View {
    self.keyboardType((keyBd == .default) ? .alphabet : keyBd)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
  }

}// extension View
```